# writing a revolute joint

Tags: python, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a door model but I can't seem to get the coding for revolute joints right. the "base_link" is the wall and "door" is the door.

My code "door.xml" is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="door">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 0.05 0.6"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.3"/>
      <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <!--<inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="100.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertia>-->
  </link>

  <link name="door">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.05 0.6"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.15 -0.025 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="hinge" type="revolute">
    <limit upper="0" lower="-1.57"velocity="10" effort="10"/>
    <origin xyz="0.3 0.025 .3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="door"/>
  </joint> 
</robot>
```

I yield the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/robot_model_visualization/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 202, in <module>
    jsp = JointStatePublisher()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/robot_model_visualization/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 25, in __init__
    robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description).getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1930, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 47, column 34
```

Here's a picture of how it looks like on rviz when I run
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=door.xml [door.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13498536029695265.png)

The visualization on rviz works perfectly find when I use continuous or fixed joints. So I'm not sure whether it is due to my code or some python related script. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04, Fuerte.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45468/writing-a-revolute-joint/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-10-09**:
I wouldn't define origin of the "door" link. It's excessive. Instead define it in the joint declaration.

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2012-10-11**:
Peter>> How do you define it in joint declaration? I want the joint to be connected to the side of the door rather than right smack in the middle. The only way I know how to shift it is to declare origin for the door. >.<

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-10-12**:
This guy is very handsome and might answer your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns&t=16m34s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message means that your XML is invalid: there's a " " missing in front of `velocity`. You can validate XML using the following command:

```
xmlstarlet val myfile.xml
```

Apart from that, your file looks good. Later, you'll want to add `<collision>` tags (just copy the `<visual>` tags).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2012-10-11**:
Thank you! It managed to generate in Rviz now :D Feel kind of stupid for not noticing that missing space. I shall try to add collision tags now. Thanks a lot.